# Mixed conditionals in a sentence

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, perfect-constructions, conditionals

- If I had won the lottery, I would **be travelling** the world.

OR

- If I had won the lottery, I would **have travelled** the world.

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Both are correct.  It all depends what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.

> If I had won the lottery, I would be travelling the world.

This means "If I had won the lottery, I would (now) be travelling the world": I'd be travelling the world now.

> If I had won the lottery, I would have travelled the world.

This means "If I had won the lottery, I would have (already) travelled the world": I'd have finished travelling the world.

Comment: "If I had won the lottery, I would be travelling the world" Is there any need to use 'had'?

Comment: We generally use past perfect when out of two actions it is necessary to emphasize that the preceding action was completely finished before the succeeding action started. "If I had win the lottery, I would be travelling the world" So, why shall we use a past perfect sentence in the if clause?

Comment: Well, you don't get the prize money until you _have won_!

Comment: "if I had won the lottery" is talking about a lottery that you have already entered but didn't win. "If I won the lottery" is talking about a lottery that you haven't entered yet or that you sometimes enter or that hasn't declared the winner yet.

Comment: I got it. Thanks rjpond.

Comment: If I had won the lottery, I would be travelling to the UK. Kate Buting :)